# Converting a string representing binary to a string representing equivalent hex

Tags: c++, string, binary, hex

So i have a string x = "10101" and i need to put into any string y the hex value of the binary in x. So if `x="10101"` then `y="0x15"`

Comment: Is there a problem with our answers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't want to provide you with the complete answer.

That said, the basic idea should be fill the start of the string with up to 3 zero's so that you can split the string into substrings with a length of 4. 
This can then easily be turned into hex by a variety of ways, the easiest being just using a switch case statement. There would only be 16 cases'

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do this is using a [bitset][1]:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    string binary_str("11001111");
    bitset<8> set(binary_str);  
    cout << hex << set.to_ulong() << endl;
}
```

But I read that it's not the most efficient way... Depends on what you whant. Remember that *premature optimisation is the root of all evil*.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `strtol` ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strtol ) function with the base 2 to convert x to the integer and then use `sprintf` to format the result string.